# PFQueryTableViewController sections by date in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, parse-platform

*First, its probably a rookie question, but I'm trying to solve it for some time and I could not.*

### Goal:

Using [PFQueryTableViewController][1], I want to have sections relating to dates.

Example: this week, next week, soon.

### Background:

The question about adding sections on a PFQueryTableViewController is discussed in this [Parse topic][2]. But the approach has nothing to do with dates intervals and I failed to adapt it to my goal.

### Question:

Please, could you guys point me out what steps should I take to get what I want? First, discriminate the entrys to different intervals of time (this week, next week, for exemple) - getting it from Parse -, and then arrange it in sections?

I'm using swift.

Thanks in advance!

---

### Edit

@danh suggested giving up the PFQTVC and start a fresh ViewController: the code to this approach, fulfilling what is asked by the question, is found in the answers, in **Objective C** and **Swift**.

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you have tried so far and why it's not working?

Comment: There are two challenges.  The first is to take a flat array and divide it into N arrays partitioned by time.  The second challenge is manipulating parse's PFQueryTableVC to deal with a 2d array instead of the default flat array.  Which challenge are you struggling with?  Please show what you've got so far and where you think it is going wrong.

Comment: @danh I edited the question with what I could do about the first challenge. But I have no idea on how to get the second part, set everything into sections.

Comment: That's a reasonable try on the partition by time, but not if you're using the PFQueryTableVC.  You'll need to return just one query in the queryForTable method, then do the division on the results from the one query.

Comment: @danh Im thinking about giving up the PFQueryTableVC on this. Maybe work with a standard UITableView to get what I want, with a sync between Parse and Core Data, would be better. What do you think? Could you give me directions about which one is the best approach? Thanks!

Comment: I could be a lot more helpful in objective-C.  Would you be able to translate if I stated advice that way?

Comment: @danh Yes. Not easily, but I will do my job! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience PFQueryTableViewController saves you a little effort and costs a lot of flexibility.  The idea with a regular `UIViewController` subclass would look like this (will try to use minimum code, because I realize objective-c is the wrong language for the OP):

Create the view controller, add a UITableView and an outlet to it called tableView.  Set the table view's datasource to be the view controller.

All table views need an array of model objects, and ours needs an array of arrays.  These will be PFObjects grouped into three arrays by date.  So we need a function to query from parse and group the results.

```
@property(weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property(strong) NSMutableArray *objects;

// in viewDidLoad, make an array of three arrays
self.objects = [NSMutableArray array];
[self.objects addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
[self.objects addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];
[self.objects addObject:[NSMutableArray array]];

// in viewDidAppear, call the fetch
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self fetchData];
}

- (void)fetchData {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MyClass"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                [self insertModel:object];
            }
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        }
    }];
}

- (void)insertModel:(PFObject *)object {
    NSDate *starts = [object valueForKey@"Starts"];
    // dates are a complex topic in iOS, since you're working in swift
    // its wasteful for me to go through the date calc in objective c.
    // see this answer in SO for how to get dates like thisWeek, nextWeek, etc:
    // http://stackoverflow.com/a/29056735/294949

    NSMutableArray *soonModel = self.model[0];
    NSMutableArray *thisWeekModel = self.model[1];
    NSMutableArray *nextWeekModel = self.model[2];
    if (/* starts in soon range */) [soonModel addObject:object];
    if (/* starts in this week range */) [thisWeekModel addObject:object];
    if (/* starts in next week range */) [nextWeekModel addObject:object];
}

- (PFObject *)objectAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSArray *section = self.model[indexPath.section];
    return section[indexPath.row];
}
```

That was the first challenge.  Call parse, and divide the results into three arrays.  Since we've jettisoned the PFQueryTableVC, we don't need to jump through any hoops to work with it.  We only need to implement the tableview datasource methods as any app would:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.model.count;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0) return @"Soon";
    if (section == 1) return @"This Week";
    if (section == 2) return @"Next Week";
    return nil;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSArray *section = self.model[section];
    return section.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // get your cell as you would in swift
    PFObject *object = [self objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // configure cell with values from object
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer @danh! I'm working on it, this is the reason for my delay to answer. When I get it I will post it here. Thank you so much again!

Comment: Happy to help.  Consider, when working on this, to decompose the work into two parts: (1) fetching and dividing PFObjects, (2) presenting a multi-section table.  I would do (2) first, just hard-code an array of arrays to test it, don't worry about parse.  Then (1.a) just prove you can get objects and divide them by some simple function, not worrying about dates which is a hard topic.  Then finally, (1.b) divide PFObjects by date.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you very much @danh, for showing me the way!

I got this working with Swift! I imagine there are some bad practices in the code, I appreciate if someone can point them out to better help those who seek for the question.

```
var container:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var thisWeek:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
var nextWeek:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()


//FetchData
func fetchData() {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "container")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            if let staffObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                for staff in staffObjects {
                    self.insertModel(staff)
                }
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            NSLog("error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

// Models
func insertModel(object: PFObject){
    var starts: NSDate = (object.valueForKey("Starts") as? NSDate)!

    // Here I managed to build the rules very easily using 
    // the SwiftDate Pod (https://github.com/malcommac/SwiftDate)
    let today = NSDate.today()
    let todayPlus7Days = today.add(years: 0, months: 0, weeks: 0, days: 7, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0)
    let todayPlus14Days = today.add(years: 0, months: 0, weeks: 0, days: 14, hours: 0, minutes: 0, seconds: 0)

    if starts >= today && starts < todayPlus7Days {
        thisWeek.addObject(object)
    }
    if starts >= todayPlus7Days && starts < todayPlus14Days{
        nextWeek.addObject(object)
    }
}

func objectAtIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> PFObject {
    var section: NSArray = container[indexPath.section] as! NSArray
    return section[indexPath.row] as! PFObject
}

// Table View
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return container.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if section == 0 { return "NEXT 7 DAYS" }
    if section == 1 { return "ANOTHERS 7 DAYS" }
    return nil
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var section: NSArray = container[section] as! NSArray
    return section.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:DestaqueTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("destaqueCell") as? DestaqueTableViewCell
    let object: PFObject = objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    // Configure cell with values from object
    return cell!
}

// - viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    container.addObject(thisWeek)
    container.addObject(nextWeek)
    fetchData()
}
```

Comment: Looks good (as far as I can understand the swift).  One thing I notice is your use of exclusive inequality operators in insertModel.  Shouldn't the bottom check (like starts > today) be inclusive (like starts >= today)?  Same thing on +7 days?  Without including the lower bounds, you might leave a tiny gap in the date ranges.  Glad you got it working.  Well done!